# Buffersize to small

Tags: sensors, accelerometer, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

## Hi!

The below problem we guess has something to do with the uart object buffersize, but not sure. We would be thankful for any insights as to how to solve the problem.

The problem appears in this line of code:

```
condition2 = 31 <= data_as_float <= 100
```

**We are using a Raspberry Pi Pico, with:**

- ADXL345 accelerometer
- Radar sensor (MR24HPB1)

If human movement is detected and a specific object is not moving, an action will be taken in the code.

**This is the problem we are encountering:**

> MPY: soft reboot
> buffer too small
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<stdin>", line 63, in <module>
> TypeError: unsupported types for **le**: 'int', 'NoneType'

**Here is the code:**

```
from machine import UART, Pin, I2C
from struct import unpack
from neopixel import NeoPixel


def low_pass_filter(prev_value, new_value, alpha):
    """This function applies a low pass filter """
    return alpha * prev_value + (1 - alpha) * new_value

def get_data_as_float(data_as_hex):
    """This function takes a hexadecimal string and returns it as a float"""

    try:
        byte_array = bytes.fromhex(data_as_hex)
        float_value = unpack('f', byte_array)[0]
        return float_value

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


# Constants
ADXL345_ADDRESS = 0x53
ADXL345_POWER_CTL = 0x2D
ADXL345_DATA_FORMAT = 0x31
ADXL345_DATAX0 = 0x32

# Instantiate sensors
uart = UART(1, 9600, bits=8, parity=None, stop=1, tx=Pin(4), rx=Pin(5))
i2c = I2C(0, sda=Pin(8), scl=Pin(9), freq=400000)
i2c.writeto_mem(ADXL345_ADDRESS, ADXL345_POWER_CTL, bytearray([0x08]))
i2c.writeto_mem(ADXL345_ADDRESS, ADXL345_DATA_FORMAT, bytearray([0x0B]))
led = NeoPixel(Pin("GP0"), 8)

# Variables for low pass
start_value = 0
alpha = 0.99

# Thresholds for accelerometer
x_thresh, y_thresh, z_thresh = 0.05, 0.5, 2.5

while True:
    # Get and process message
    message = uart.read()
    if message is not None:
        message = message.hex()
        function_code = message[6:8]
        address1 = message[8:10]
        address2 = message[10:12]
        data = message[12:-4]
        data_as_float = get_data_as_float(data)
        
        # Get and process xyz
        xyz = i2c.readfrom_mem(ADXL345_ADDRESS, ADXL345_DATAX0, 6)
        x, y, z = unpack('<3h', xyz)
        x, y, z = abs(x), abs(y), abs(z)
        filtered_x = low_pass_filter(start_value, x, alpha)
        filtered_y = low_pass_filter(start_value, y, alpha)
        filtered_z = low_pass_filter(start_value, z, alpha)
        
        # Conditions
        condition1 = function_code == "04" and address1 == "03" and address2 == "06"
        condition2 = 31 <= data_as_float <= 100
        condition3 = x < x_thresh and y < y_thresh and z < z_thresh
        
        if condition1 and condition2 and condition3:
            print("Yay")
```

We tried to increase txbuf and rxbuf parameters when initializing the radar sensor, but to no effect, same problem.

We are new to working this close to the hardware and it's a bit complicated for us at the moment.

Comment: Check the size of `message` before you process it. You are apparently passing junk data to `get_data_as_float` which is too small.  Also, I recommend removing the `try/finally` block in `get_data_as_float`, since it just causes that function to return `None` instead of actually handling the error in a reasonable way, and that is causing later parts of your program to crash when they try to use the returned value.  You probably need to be smarter about how you read the UART to ensure you get a complete message and nothing else.  UART serial doesn't have message boundaries.

Comment: Additionally, don't ignore the warning regarding your comparison `"TypeError: unsupported types for le: 'int', 'NoneType'"`. I don't use python extensively, but that seems to indicate your `... <= data_as_float ...` isn't providing needed type information.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the `unsupported types` error tells us that `data_as_float` had the value `None`, so it can't be compared with an `int`.

Comment: @nekomatic - thank you for the clarification. I can find my way around python if needed, but prefer C. The finer points of type compatibility in python is something I've yet to commit to memory. I've found using the pico-SDK and `openocd` with a 2nd pico as a debug probe a far more efficient way to program the device. Works equally well from Linux or Windows with Msys2.